# Google Play Services Sign-in failed to complete

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I'm trying to implement Sign-in in my game.

After I start my game Sign-in starts, I can see text "Google Play Games" on a green background with a logo above it, after that loading spinner starts to spin and shortly after that Sign-in fails, it just exits from Sign-in without any message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you share the log from logcat?
Typically this is due to a configuration problem.  Double check:

1. The game_ids.xml has been updated with the values from the Play Developer Console.
2. Confirm that your packageName (or ApplicationId in the build.gradle) matches what is configured for the linked Android application for your game.
3. Confirm that the SHA1 fingerprint is for the keystore you are using to sign your application matches the one entered in the linked Android app.
4. Confirm that the default player on your device is added as a tester for your game.